# Unable to see Automatically assign to queue, under select Approver?

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

[image]

How to add  Automatically assign to queue, under select Approver options?

Answer (score 0):

As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.approvals_step_approver.htm&type=5),  '**Automatically assign to a queue**' option to assign approval requests to a queue is available only for objects that support queues.

To check list of objects supported in your org navigate to Quick Find-->Queues-->New, you can see list under available objects.

[image]